File changes do not take effect in xcode untill clean build folder
When I upgrade to Xcode 15.x, I have to clean the build folder every time after I modify some files, otherwise the code I wrote will not take effect.
I tried reinstall the xcode, restart my mac, even reset the macos system, but nothing works

Yeah, I'm seeing the same issue after moving to a new laptop. XCode 15.3 was working fine on the old one. On the new laptop I can change source code and run the app but my changes are not incorporated into it. It is not bound to one project, tried on few projects and the issue persists.

For me it only seems to be happening while running iOS app on macOS (in iPad mode). If I try to run it on simulator or actual device, it updates as expected.

@Const yeah, I found it only happens while running iOS app on macOS too
